# [Stuck]: Final step of solving limit, Calculus I

Tags: calculus, limits, taylor-expansion

Calculate the value of $k$ such that the following limit has a finite solution, $L$ such that $L \ne 0$:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0} \frac{(e^{x^2}-x^2-1)(\cos(x)-1)}{x^k}$$

I use the Taylor Series expansions of $e^x$ and $\cos(x)$ and simplify the above expression to the following:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0} \frac{-\frac{1}{4}x^6+(\frac{1}{48}-\frac{1}{12})x^8+(\frac{1}{144})x^{10}}{x^k}$$

Now I have a mental roadblock. For $k<6$ the above limit goes to zero and for $k>6$ this expression should diverge but in my head it goes to zero again.... I am trying to think of a simple example to convince myself but can't. Can someone please help me understand this?

Thanks.

Comment: take for example $k=7$ and divide each term on the numerator by the denominator $x^7$. What do you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0} \frac{-\frac{1}{4}x^6+(\frac{1}{48}-\frac{1}{12})x^8+(\frac{1}{144})x^{10}}{x^k}=\\
=\lim_{x\rightarrow0} -\frac{1}{4}x^{6-k}+(\frac{1}{48}-\frac{1}{12})x^{8-k}+(\frac{1}{144})x^{10-k} $$

If any of the exponents is negative, then the limit goes to infinity, so you must have $k\le 6$.
Also if all exponents are (stricly) positive (this happens iff $k<6$) then the limit goes to zero.

Then you must have $k=6$.

> for $k>6$ this expression should diverge but in my head it goes to zero again....

Why? If $k>6$, the first (at least) summand goes to infinity.

The standard recipe for limits with polynomials is: "When $x$ goes to infinity, the highest degree term rules; when $x$ goes to zero, the lowest degree term rules". Here, this suggests to factor the ruling term from the fraction and write it as

$$ x^{6-k} ( a + b x^2 +cx^4)$$
for some non-zero $a,b,c$. Then, we quickly see that as $x\to 0$ the factor in parentheses tends to the constant $a$, and we have the three cases: if $k<6$ the left factor tends to zero, if $k>6$ it tends to infinity, if $k=6$ it tends to one (and hence the limit to $a$).

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative derivation, we have that

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0} \frac{(e^{x^2}-x^2-1)(\cos x-1)}{x^k}
=\lim_{x\rightarrow0} \frac{e^{x^2}-x^2-1}{x^{k-2}}\lim_{x\rightarrow0} \frac{\cos x-1}{x^2}=-\frac12\lim_{x\rightarrow0} \frac{e^{x^2}-x^2-1}{x^{k-2}}$$

then recall that

$$e^{x^2}=1+x^2+\frac12x^4+o(x^4)$$

and then for $k=6$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0} \frac{e^{x^2}-x^2-1}{x^{4}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0} \frac{\frac12x^4+o(x^4)}{x^{4}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0} \frac{\frac12+o(1)}{1}=\frac12$$

and therefore

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0} \frac{(e^{x^2}-x^2-1)(\cos x-1)}{x^6}=-\frac14$$

Comment: You should get rid of those limit signs at the beginning. They clutter up the page, but more importantly, you don't know the limits exist until you prove they do.

Comment: @zhw I agree totally with you, indeed 99.99% of my solutions for limit are without limit signs!

Comment: @zhw. I also don't use limit separation but in latest days I've seen many users solving in that way and so I've decided to change the method a little bit. Moreover here the separation is useful because we can apply Taylor's expansion only to a part using for the other one a standard limit.

Comment: @zhw. Yes of course we are not sure "a priori" whether the separation works or not but "a poteriori" we know that it works.

Comment: But a good proof flows from the unknown to the known. Also, just because some users exhibit bad habits doesn't mean you should. I posted an answer (which I will delete in due time) that is the same as yours but without the extra unneeded stuff.

Comment: @zhw. That’s nice let it there as reference. Thanks! Bye

Comment: Limit separation always works in case of product/quotient when the limit being separated is non-zero. This is independent of the behavior of other factor. So it is apriori judgement.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh No, you missed the point: to write $\lim f(x)g(x)=\lim f(x)\cdot\lim g(x)$, one must first know that $\lim f(x)$ and $\lim g(x)$ both exist.

Comment: @Did: well the existence of both the limits is sufficient but not necessary. If one of the limits is non-zero say $f\to L\neq 0$ then $\lim fg=L\lim g$. The meaning of the last equation is that the behavior of $fg$ is similar to that of $g$: if $g$ diverges, converges or oscillates then so does $fg$. It is in this sense that we can do the separation. The separation does not work if $L=0$ because you may be unlucky enough to get $0\times \infty$ case. The case when both limits exist is more commonly found in textbooks.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh The point was raised to my attention by zwh and I agree with his suggestion (he has solved as usual I solve these kind of problem). I also understand your point of course and I think it is good too. Indeed, as the problem set implicitely states, we can assume as an initial hypotesis that the limit exist for some $k$ and the final result confirms that assumption for $k=6$.

Answer (score 0):

$\cos x-1\sim -\frac{1}{2}x^2$ and $e^{x^2}-x^2-1\sim\frac{1}{2}x^4$,
So $k=6$ and $L=-\frac{1}{4}$.